# How can I get my AMD GPU to work in Linux under OpenCL?

Tags: rendering, gpu, drivers, linux, opencl

OS: Arch Linux kernel 4.7.6-1
GPU Driver: AMDGPU 1.1.2-1
Xorg version: 1.18.4-1
Blender version: 2.78.a-1 (latest in official Arch repo)

I'm 100% sure Xorg is loading the GPU driver based on the log file `/var/Xorg/Xorg.1.log`. I've enabled OpenCL with: `CYCLES_OPENCL_SPLIT_KERNEL_TEST=1 blender` and then I selected my GPU under User Preferences > System > Compute Device > OpenCL > AMD FIJI GPU.

Under the scene settings, I switched Compute device from CPU to GPU. And I of course switched to Cycles Engine.

When trying to render things, however, blender throws an error about being unable to find the CPU known as FIJI and renders nothing.

**How do I get my Fury X to render in blender on Linux?**

I don't have an integrated GPU on my CPU, so unless only one process can deal with the GPU at a time (which shouldn't be the case), Xorg should be able to share my GPU with blender.

Comment: You won't get GPU rendering with the opensource drivers. If you want to use GPU rendering you'll have to switch to fglrx.

Comment: I heard someone complaining that 2.78a solved many bugs but broke opencl (http://www.blendernation.com/2016/10/26/blender-2-78a-fixes-69-bugs/#comment-712356), can't confirm though...

Comment: Any update on this? [Here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Blender#Blender_does_not_show_the_AMD_card_as_an_OpenCL_rendering_device) on the Arch Linux Wiki it says that you either have to use AMDGPU-PRO (proprietary amd driver) or you can use the open source OpenGL driver and the closed source OpenCL driver (`opencl-amd`)